# how i can do this by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have 2 line want make it one line and do the same job

```
RewriteRule ^account/?$ account.php
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)/?$ account.php?mod=$1
```

how i can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)/?$ account.php?mod=$1
```

is enough if account.php can deal with an empty mod, otherwise you will need both rules.

Answer (score 2):

The real merge of both rules would be:

```
RewriteRule ^account/?(.*)/?$ account.php?mod=$1
```

but it will not behave as you expect if you have URLs like `account-info/foo/` which will then be mapped to `account.php?mod=-info/foo`.

If you have other URLs starting with *account*, go with Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer.

Comment: oh god i want it like that account.php?mod=foo

Comment: @moustafa: I know, what do you mean with your comment?